# WebSphere FFDC Count, what does it mean?

Tags: websphere, websphere-6.1, websphere-portal

I am trying to understand what the "Count" column means in a WebSphere FFDC exception log.  IBM told us we have received this error 6835 times.  I have not found a good guide which explains what this count shows but from what I have seen it seems to be the number of times that this exception happened since the last JVM restart.  The problem is that does not match up with our logs as this error only appears to be thrown 1 time per day with our daily restarts which I can see in the Systemout.log.  Also this count doesn't seem to change over a weeks time in the exception logs.  Can anyone help?

Index  Count   Time of last Occurrence   Exception SourceId ProbeId
------+------+---------------------------+--------------------------
    21   6835    11/19/11 7:00:17:631 UTC java.util.zip.ZipException com.ibm.ws.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.addDependents 238

Comment: That FFDC incident will only occur when shared libraries are processed (i.e., at server start for server-assocated shared libraries, or at application start for app/module-associated shared libraries).

Answer (score 4):

This website may be helpful: http://wasdynacache.blogspot.com/2011_07_01_archive.html (Section entitled "First Failure Data Capture for your enterprise application with WebSphere Application Server")

> FFDC is capturing the state of the application server and/or the
>   application when an unexpected error or exception occurs the first
>   time. All subsequent iterations of the same error/exception are
>   ignored.

I tried seeing if I could find information for you specifically about count, but all FFDC logs can be formatted differently depending on which application calls it and which formatter the call uses.  Good luck.